# Collect text cells based on condition like sumif

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table which looks kind of like this:

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Carrot | Vegetable |
| Apple | Fruit |
| Tomato | Vegetable |
| Pear | Fruit |

The output I need should look like this:

| Type | Names |
| --- | --- |
| Vegetable | Carrot, Tomato |
| Fruit | Apple, Pear |

Basically I only need a function that can collect all strings in a column that fit a certain condition and return them as a comma separated string (Names column). I think it should work similar to `sumif()` but obviously it only works with numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution:
`=CONCAT(FILTER(A2:A5; B2:B5="Fruit")&", ")` returns `Apple, Pear,` only need to figure out that last comma now

This one is even better:
`=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE;FILTER(A2:A5; B2:B5="Fruit"))`
does the job as needed